# Type Mismatch - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of Integers(`h_current`) with some values and some are blank.
When there are no values, excel VBA sometimes labels  the type  as `Variant/EMPTY` and sometimes as `Variant/String`. 
What is the reason behind this?

When it is `EMPTY` type, I can use it for addition with any integer(for ex: `hinitial`)  but when it is `STRING` type, of course the code fails!

```
t_step=0
Dim hinitial As Integer
Dim h_current As Variant
hinitial = Worksheets("LatLen").Cells(2 + t_step, 9)

Do while(something something)
h_current = Worksheets("LatLen").Cells(3 + t_step, 9)
  If (Not IsNull(h_current)) Then
   Worksheets("LatLen").Cells(3 + t_step, 11).Value = h_current + hinitial
  Else
   Worksheets("LatLen").Cells(3 + t_step, 11).Value = h_current
   hinitial = h_current  'FAILS HERE when h_current is VARIANT/STRING
  End If
 t_step = t_step + 1
Loop
```

Comment: `Empty` means there is nothing in the cell.  A null string though would be generated if the cell contained either a null string, or a formula that returned a null string.

Comment: Thanks! @YowE3k But Is there a way to convert those string type to Empty type? The column has 8000 rows. It isn't feasible to go through each row. What may I add in the code such that string is assigned as empty?

Comment: @YowE3K : please see above! thnx

Comment: I find it strange that `h_current` is a `Variant/String` at the line you say it crashes at - it should be a `Variant/Null` if it gets to that point.

Comment: To answer your specific question, just say `If h_current = "" Then h_current = Empty` but, as I mention in my previous comment, that does not seem to be the issue you have - both `Empty` and `""` would be going through the `True` leg of your `If`.